# Gorm Timestamps in Golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
type Base struct {
    ID          uint            `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time       `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time       `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt   *gorm.DeletedAt `sql:"index" json:"deleted_at" swaggertype:"primitive,string"`
    CreatedByID uint            `gorm:"column:created_by_id" json:"created_by_id"`
    UpdatedByID uint            `gorm:"column:updated_by_id" json:"updated_by_id"`
}
```

If I pass some values to created_at and updated_at it is taking up the current time as a default value and not taking up the value that I have passed. Is there any way I can make the gorm take up the values that I have passed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three ways

1. Define [default tag](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values) for field with a **database** function to fill in the default. e.g. for MySQL database `current_timestamp()` can be used

```
     CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"`
```

2. Assign default values as suggested by @Guolei.
3. Embed `gorm.Model` in your struct instead, for automatic handling of ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt and DeletedAt.

Comment: Any way to save the timestmp in UTC by default?

Answer (score 2):

An update to @s3vt's answer:

If you the first method they provided, you need to put the function without the parenthesis like this:

```
CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp"`
```

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the error I was getting so I thought I'd share it for the people who might face this!

Comment: This solves the syntax error from `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"` if used. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

if containing fileds: CreatedAt and UpdatedAt, gorm will use reflect to insert default value when executing.
also you could give the specific value.

```
info := Example{
    CreatedAt: time.Now(),
    UpdatedAt: time.Now(),
}
_, err := DB.Insert(info)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the gorm.Model now automatically import the created_at, updated_at, and deleted_at on 2023. Here is my model

[image]

and here is the result[image]

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more